# How switch full screen in a pygame surface window

Tags: pygame

How can I make my Pygame surface to be full screen? I have tried the following:

```
pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
```

but it does not do what I need.

Comment: When you call `pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()`, what is it doing or not doing that's insufficient?

Comment: It does not do anything on windows! I tried pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen() on Rasberri pi and it does what I want which is very good because I was ultimately going to put my program from Windows on Raspberri Pi.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is not really a elegant, but you could call Pygames `display.set_mode()` function each time you want to change your screen mode (i.e. size, display flags).

You need to shut down the entire display module `display.quit()` first and initialize `display.init()` it again afterwards.

```
import pygame as pyg

pyg.init()
screen = pyg.display.set_mode((200, 300), pyg.RESIZABLE)

screen.fill((255,155,55))
pyg.display.flip()

while True:

    ev = pyg.event.wait()

    if ev.type == pyg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and ev.button == 1:
        # Display in Fullscreen mode
        pyg.display.quit()
        pyg.display.init()
        screen = pyg.display.set_mode((0, 0), pyg.FULLSCREEN)

    elif ev.type == pyg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and ev.button == 2:
        # Display in Resizable mode
        pyg.display.quit()
        pyg.display.init()
        screen = pyg.display.set_mode((200, 300), pyg.RESIZABLE)

    screen.fill((255,155,55))
    pyg.display.flip()
```

Comment: You actually only need to call `pyg.screen.flip` :)

Answer (score 0):

Grabbed this from somewhere a while back, can't remember the source:

```
display = (1280,720) #whatever you want the screen size to be
if event.key == K_h: #Just a key to toggle fullscreen
    if pygame.display.get_driver()=='x11':
        pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
    else:
        acopy=screen.copy()                    
    if fullscreen:
        screen=pygame.display.set_mode(display)
    else:
        screen=pygame.display.set_mode(display, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        fullscreen= not fullscreen
        screen.blit(acopy, (0,0))                    
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks elegent for your answer. I finally found the answer from some othere post that was not even intended to answer my question:

```
import pygame
import ctypes

def set_screen_prop():
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    screenSize =  user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
    print screenSize
    size = (screenSize)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Window")
    return pygame.display.set_mode((size) , pygame.FULLSCREEN)

pygame.init()
window=set_screen_prop()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: why code in python if - in the end - your program will only run on a single OS?!